# Installing a comprehensive LAPACK implementation under Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, programming, c

I would like to ask how to properly install a comprehensive LAPACK package
as e.g. is offered by the Gentoo package 'sci-libs/clapack' within a Ubuntu
environment.

I am not talking about atlas here, which only offers a small part of lapack
functionality, but a more general solution offering functions for e.g.
eigen value problems like 'dstegr'.

Here is what I achieved so far: My favorite search command

```
apt-file search clapack.h
```

offered only two possible sources.

```
libatlas-dev: /usr/include/atlas/clapack.h
libfreefem++-dev: /usr/include/freefem++/clapack.h
```

As mentioned, the atlas version is not, what I want. The libfreefem variation
on the other hand reads fine. So

```
apt-get install libfreefem++-dev
```

In addition

```
apt-cache search lapack
```

offers a lot, the most promising looking lines being

```
liblapack-dev - library of linear algebra routines 3 - static version
liblapack3gf - library of linear algebra routines 3 - shared version
```

the first package of which I installed. Now adding

```
#include <freefem++/clapack.h>
```

into my program returns an understandable long list of errors in the style

'integer', 'real', 'doublereal', ... was not declared in this scope

as in fact they were not. Anyways I am not looking
for freefem or atlas but just a running, usable LAPACK implementation
is there really no such thing for Ubuntu?

Rereading my own post I believe the question might also be boiled down to
"Where can I obtain a comprehensive header file for 'liblapack-dev'"?

Comment: Did you actually install said software? Seems like the compiler is complaining about something that should'v been included but wasn't (looks like the software wasn't installed, at least not properly installed).

Comment: Hi Alex! Yes I did. Actually I took a good look at the /usr/include/atlas/clapack.h file. It only has an include cblas.h and about 35 (give or take) function declarations. The coveted eigenvector methods are not among them.

Comment: Or do you mean the FreeFem approach? Maybe I will follow this up today. FreeFem actually offers a load of headers some of which probably declare the missing types. But if somehow possible I would like to reduce my actually Lapack dependent source to a single include clapack.h so I will google some more before I concede to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution that works for me. The bottom line for those who might read this at a later time and with a similar problem: I went to the [LAPACK homepage](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), downloaded the most recent version of LAPACK as a tar gz, unpacked it and followed the **instructions issued on installation guide** on the same site. Trouble I ran into: In the Makefile I had to reduce the line

```
all: lapack_install lib blas_testing lapack_testing
```

to

```
all: lapack_install lib
```

After that

```
make
```

gave me ./liblapack.a and ./libtmglib.a.

So much so Fortran. However, I want something for inserting into a C program. This means I also want LAPACKE.

It may be found in the subdirektory ./lapacke/. There is a CMakeLists.txt which I ignored, calling the already present Makefile directly (it is short and easy to read and it uses the make.inc file you create when you follow the **installation guide** mentioned aboce). Single drawback here was the lack of [lapacke_mangling.h](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke_mangling.h) which I had to copy into ./lapacke/include/.

This done the call to "make" from inside the directory ./lapacke/ ran with no trouble creating ./lapacke.a and I was ready to write a little demo program:

```
/**
 * svd_demo.cpp
 * 
 * Given that you put version 3.5.0 into /opt/lapack/ compile this with: 
 * g++ svd_demo.cpp -I"/opt/lapack/lapack-3.5.0/lapacke/include" \
 *   -L"/opt/lapack/lapack-3.5.0" -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lcblas
 * The order of included libraries is important!
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <lapacke.h>

using namespace std;

typedef double value;

/** Column major style! */
string matrix2string(int m, int n, value* A)
{
  ostringstream oss;
  for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
  {
    for (int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
      oss << A[j+k*m] << "\t";
    }
    oss << endl;
  }
  return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //> Part 1. Decomposition. -----------------------------------------
  char jobu  = 'A'; // Return the complete matrix U
  char jobvt = 'A'; // Return the complete matrix VT
  int mA = 2;
  int nA = 3;
  int lda = 2;
  int ldu = 2;
  int ldvt = 3;
  int lwork = 81;
  int info = 0;
  value* A = (value*)malloc(mA*nA*sizeof(value));
  value* U = (value*)malloc(mA*mA*sizeof(value));
  value* VT = (value*)malloc(nA*nA*sizeof(value));
  value* Svec = (value*)malloc(3*sizeof(value));
  value* work = (value*)malloc(lwork*sizeof(value));

  A[0] = 1; A[2] = 2; A[4] = 4;
  A[1] = 0; A[3] = 0; A[5] = 4;

  cout << "Matrix A (will be overwritten, as is documented):" << endl <<
    matrix2string(mA,nA,A);

  // Citing lapacke.h
  //lapack_int LAPACKE_dgesvd(int matrix_order, char jobu, char jobvt,
  //   lapack_int m, lapack_int n, double* a,
  //   lapack_int lda, double* s, double* u, lapack_int ldu,
  //   double* vt, lapack_int ldvt, double* superb);

  info = LAPACKE_dgesvd(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, jobu, jobvt, mA, nA, A, lda, Svec, U, ldu, VT, ldvt, work);
  cout << "Ran dgesvd. Let's see ..." << endl <<
    "U:" << endl << matrix2string(mA,mA,U) <<
    "Svec:" << endl << matrix2string(1,nA,Svec) <<
    "VT:" << endl << matrix2string(nA,nA,VT) <<
    "Info Code: " << info << endl << endl <<
    "All is well." << endl;
  //< ----------------------------------------------------------------
  //> Part 2. Checking the result. -----------------------------------
  value* S = (value*)malloc(mA*nA*sizeof(value));
  S[0] = Svec[0]; S[2] = 0      ; S[4] = 0      ;
  S[1] = 0      ; S[3] = Svec[1]; S[5] = 0      ;

  // Citing cblas.h
  // void cblas_dgemm(const enum CBLAS_ORDER Order, const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA,
  //   const enum CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransB, const int M, const int N,
  //   const int K, const double alpha, const double *A,
  //   const int lda, const double *B, const int ldb,
  //   const double beta, double *C, const int ldc);

  // work := S*VT; (2x3)=(2x3)*(3x3)
  cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,mA,nA,nA,1,S,lda,VT,ldvt,0,work,lda)    ;
  cout << "Step 1: S*VT" << endl << matrix2string(2,3,work);

  // A := U*work; (2x2)*(2x3)
  cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,CblasNoTrans,mA,nA,mA,1,U,ldu,work,lda,0,A,lda);
  cout << "A := U*S*VT:" << endl << matrix2string(mA,nA,A) << endl;
  //< ----------------------------------------------------------------
  free(A); free(U); free(VT); free(Svec); free(work); free(S);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which on my system now produces the output

```
1       2       4
0       0       4
Ran dgesvd. Let's see ...
U:
-0.759729       -0.65024
-0.65024        0.759729
Svec:
5.89017 1.51851 0
VT:
-0.128982       -0.257965       -0.957506
-0.42821        -0.856419       0.288414
-0.894427       0.447214        -7.48099e-18
Info Code: 0

All is well.
Step 1: S*VT
-0.759729       -1.51946        -5.63988
-0.65024        -1.30048        0.437958
A := U*S*VT:
1       2       4
-9.63558e-16    -4.86265e-17    4
```

In terms of BLAS I installed

```
libblas-dev - Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines 3, static library
libblas3gf - Basic Linear Algebra Reference implementations, shared library
libopenblas-dev - Optimized BLAS (linear algebra) library based on GotoBLAS2
```

Consequently in the Lapack main Makefile I used

```
BLASLIB = /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.a
```

Answer (score 10):

I got the same result by using package manager. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libblas-doc checkinstall
sudo apt-get install liblapacke-dev checkinstall
sudo apt-get install liblapack-doc checkinstall
```

The libraries went in /usr/lib and the includes in /usr/include.

Thanks to [Markus-Hermann](https://askubuntu.com/users/87693/markus-hermann) for the example code in the previous post. It helped me test it out real quick. Using the default install directories I used the following command:

```
g++ svd_demo.cpp -I"/usr/include" -L"/usr/lib" -llapacke -lblas
```

Comment: Is this an answer? It doesn't look much like one...

Comment: Well, what I described is a way to properly install a comprehensive LAPACK package in ubuntu. I am using ubuntu 14.04.1. I came to this page while looking to do that, so wanted to post a quicker solution than the one presented.

Comment: A year later on a new computer I come back to my old post and decide to try your short solution. And what do you know... it actually works! :-)

Comment: It works for me as well, great relief (I even skipped installing libblas-doc).