# Installation and Use of LAPACK 3.5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, laptop

I am facing problems while installing `LAPACK 3.5.0`. I have already seen this nicely [written answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417726/installing-a-comprehensive-lapack-implementation-under-ubuntu) but I didn't understand anything out of it (as OP was knowing what problem he was facing). Since I am new to LAPACK that means I have never used it before. If you can help me from scratch, I would be very thankful.

I have already edited some of the files as directed [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn81/node10.html) but they have given lot more information than that, which may be required for the installation of the same. But due to this extra information, I am not able to proceed further. I Need your help.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I am installing `fortran` version; I don't know how to use it. Help me, in this case.

Comment: how did you installed it?

Comment: @BillGates, I have not yet installed anything, got stuck in midway.

Comment: @KasiyA, i.e. for C++, there is a difference between fortran one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Installation and use of...not just installation only.

Comment: @Parto Ya you are right.

Answer (score 0):

LAPACK 3.5.0 is in the [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liblapack3)

LAPACK can be installed as

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack3
```

Comment: I want to install fortran version, and there is no as such description given there, but here it is given here http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgfortran3